# Modal overlay appearing over fixed div

Tags: html, css, overlay, z-index, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS and I have this problem with some CSS where a modal overlay that is a button does not appear over the top of other elements that are set as `fixed`.

The below link is the code and [here is the preview](https://vre8j.csb.app/) of the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-vre8j

The div's border and tag backgrounds are above the overlay

I've tried to set the `z-index` of both the overlay and container of problem div but it ignores it.

The example here is a stripped-down version of the actual page. Removed them as much irrelevant stuff as I could to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have z-index on overlay to be greater than on other elements.
https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-hdx75

Here you can see that I've used z-10 for "billy bob junior box" and z-20 for the overlay and its wrapper

Comment: ah! that's what I was doing wrong, I had tried similar to what you did, I just never added one to the top-level fixed div. Thanks!